# Array_Constrain or Query slowing sheet down

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have what should be a very simple, speedy sheet which is running exceptionally slowly (and crashing on some computers). The problem appears to be on the Q's and A's sheet, which does have 2000 rows (necessary), but that shouldn't be slowing it down as much as it is. I am using this formula to create an array of values to help populate dependent dropdown lists:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(a2:a2000="",,ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TRIM(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IF(TRANSPOSE(C2:C2000)=List!C2:C200,List!D2:D200&"---",),,10))),"---")),COUNTA(C2:C2000),10)))
```

I got this formula from a forum, as it uses a technique I'm not familiar with, so I believe this to be causing the problem. What I need is to have the helper cells on the right side populate with the correct options based on currently selected items in the first dropdowns. The formula works (and much better than my previous filter formula copied down 2000 rows), but it seems something is wrong that is causing the Sheet to run and load extremely slowly. I'm at a loss now of what else to do to speed this up, as neither this formula nor the previous filter function are doing the trick.

You can see the sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Gxwa4l1s5APHFtioOvikMOS8qXyqJRWBd8PbJa5J5Q/edit?usp=sharing

If the Sheet loads, you can see the speed issue by changing any of the dropdown selections, as it takes it at least 10-20 seconds to update the query results.

In case you can't load it, here is a screenshot of a portion of the sheet that has the formula and likely the issue:
[image: screenshot of problem area]

I've been trying the ideas in the chat with no success yet. The big issue is that the dropdown lists populate based on the dropdown lists, so there is circular dependency going on. What I need is to quickly populate lists of Q&A column D values that have matching values in Q&A Column C to the value in a relative cell in Q&A column C. I am using the Lists tab to generate smaller lists, but they still depend on Q&A columns.

UPDATE:
While I received a lot of help and ideas here, there really seems to be no good solution in the way I wanted. So, I decided on a script solution. If you've found this question because you have a similar issue, here is the code I'm using to populate the helper cells and thus the dropdown menus

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var listSheet = ss.getSheetByName("List");
  var lastRow = listSheet.getLastRow();
  var cats = listSheet.getRange(2,3,lastRow,11).getDisplayValues();
  var catsLength = cats.length-1;
  var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = activeCell.getRow();
  var cat = sheet.getRange(row,3,1,4).getDisplayValues();
  var catVals = [];
  var subCat1Vals = [];
  var subCat2Vals = [];
  if(sheetName=='Q\'s and A\'s'){
    sheet.getRange(row,7,1,30).clearContent();

      for (i=0; i<=catsLength; i++){
        if (cat[0][0] == cats[i][0] && cats[i][1] != ""){
          catVals = catVals.concat(cats[i][1]);
        }
        if (cat[0][0] == cats[i][8] && cat[0][1] == cats[i][9] && cats[i][10] != ""){
          subCat1Vals = subCat1Vals.concat(cats[i][10]);
        }
        if (cat[0][0] == cats[i][3] && cat[0][1] == cats[i][4] && cat[0][2] == cats[i][5] && cats[i][6] != ""){
          subCat2Vals = subCat2Vals.concat(cats[i][6]);
        }
      }
      var cols = catVals.length;
      sheet.getRange(row,7,1,cols).setValues([catVals]); 
      var cols = subCat1Vals.length;
      sheet.getRange(row,17,1,cols).setValues([subCat1Vals]);
      var cols = subCat2Vals.length;
      sheet.getRange(row,27,1,cols).setValues([subCat2Vals]); 
  }
}
```

Comment: i can't even open the sheet myself, do you have an example/screenshot of what should be the expected result of what you want please ? anyway I think it might have to have something with the fact that you are using `9^99` in your sheet, that is almost 3 with 94 zeros next to it

Comment: have you tried to instead of 9^99 use 9^5 or 9^6

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, so I changed it to 10 in the three queries. Still pretty slow though, but maybe it will load for you now. I've added a screenshot as well.

Comment: still can't open the Q&A sheet. 10^10 is one hundred billion, could you please change it to 4 or 5 so I can take a look at it please ?

Comment: I actually changed it to just 10. Not 10^anything. Any other ideas? It loads for me fine, just slow, but my client can't load it either. I'll try removing a ton of rows for now, that might do it.

Comment: please backup your sheet so you have a copy of the original please

Comment: No worries. This is a copy as it is. The original is still safe. And FYI, it runs quite quickly now with just 20 rows. But it will need to go to 2000 rows in the end, so hopefully you all can diagnose the problem even when it isn't present ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222207/discussion-between-nabais-and-brian-rgy-studio).